# C struct malloc & array of pointers implementation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I just started programming in C a few days ago. I am now trying to learn structs.

I have this program and **I want to improve it so that my array people is now an array of pointers to structs.** I am not sure how to do this.

**I also want to modify my insert method, to call malloc to create a new struct and set the correct array element pointing to it.**

As far as I know, malloc is dinamic memory allocation but although I've read some guides I'm still unsure on how exactly to use it. Also, after using malloc, what else do I need to change in my program for it to work as before?

Comment: (I already saw this question today.... you or someone else recently posted this code).

Comment: Yes, it was probably my friend Sarah. She's working on the same exercise as I am. She had some compilation errors which I didn't fortunately :D However, I am unsure how to improve my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `people` to be an array of pointers, you have to declare it like this:

```
struct person *people[12];
```

Remember that declaration follows use and that dereferencing has lower precedence than array indexing; this means that `*people[i]` is of type `struct person`, and thus, `people[i]` is a pointer to `struct person`.

To initialize each position in `people`, you call `malloc()` to make your pointers point to a valid memory location large enough to hold a `struct person`. It is as easy as:

```
people[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
```

When you don't need `people` anymore, you have to remember to free every memory position you allocated, by calling `free(people[i])` for every position `i`.

I noticed you declared the array to hold 12 structs. This can be dangerous when someone changes the code: it will not work when `HOW_MANY` is greater than 12. You should declare an array of the same size:

```
struct person *people[HOW_MANY];
```

This ensures that your array always has exactly the space needed.

**UPDATE:**
You need to declare `insert` as receiving an array of pointers instead of an array of structures:

> static void insert (struct person *people[], char *name, int age) {
>   ... }

And `people[i].name` is invalid. Since `people[i]` is a pointer now, you need to do it like this:

```
people[i]->name
```

Or, equivalently, `(*people[i]).name`.

The same applies to `people[i]->age`. Remember to change this both in `main()` and inside `insert`.

Also, consider passing `i` to `insert` instead of using `static` variables, unless you have a very good reason to do so. Static variables are used for functions with internal state, and for me, `insert` is not quite the type of function where you'd want that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Filipe! I'm guessing I need a for loop to include free in, is that right?

Comment: Yep, by the time you don't need `people`, you'll have to make a loop like `for (i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) free(people[i]);`. Also, why do you keep static variables inside `insert`? Any special reason not to pass `i` to `insert`?

Comment: I've edited the code to what you suggested, but apparently there is a bug in it. I am getting an incompatible pointer type exception.

Comment: arrays.c:42: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘insert’ from incompatible pointer type
arrays.c:21: note: expected ‘struct person *’ but argument is of type ‘struct person **’
arrays.c:52: error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union
arrays.c:53: error: request for member ‘age’ in something not a structure or union